# 「のは」 vs. 「には」 -- as in 「嬉しいのは嬉しい」 「あるにはある」

Tags: usage, expressions, particle-に, particle-は, particle-の

Related: [What is the meaning of 「読むには読んだ」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34564/16344) 
Related: [には with plain form of verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29886/%e3%81%ab%e3%81%af-with-plain-form-of-verb)

> [dictionary.goo.ne.jp 「には」](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/167736/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF/) 
> ３.  （多く「…には…が」の形で、動詞や形容詞を繰り返して）一応その動作や状態は認めるが、それに関連して起こる動作や状態については関知したり容認したりしない意を表す。 「推薦状は、書く―書くが、あまり期待しないでくれ」 「涼しい―涼しいが、ちょっと冷えすぎる」

1. [dictionary.goo.ne.jp] doen't have a similar entry for 「のは」 -- Does this mean that  「には」  is more "canonical" ?
2. Are they related (one deriving from the other) ?
3. 「涼しいのは涼しい」 vs. 「涼しいには涼しい」 -- I think the former is more common (tentatively confirmed by Google hit numbers). Is there a difference in meaning?   What's the rule for choosing one over the other? ( 「のは」 vs. 「には」 )

> [thesaurus.weblio.jp  「あるにはある」](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B)  ==  物事の有無について、ないことを否定する表現
>
> (Syn.) :  無くはない  ・  ないとは言えない  ・  無いわけではない  ・  ないと言えば嘘になる  ・  あるにはある  ・  有るか無いかと問われればある

追加：　あると言えばある（んだが）、　嬉しいと言えば嬉しい（んだが）、・・・

いわゆる、「奥歯に物が（の）挟まったような言い方」　ですねｗ

Comment: Probably, verbs go with には and i-adjectives go with のは.

Answer (score 4):

Google hit counts is extremely unreliable; you have to use a corpus whenever possible. According to [BCCWJ](http://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/),

- あるにはある 58 hits
- あることはある 19 hits
- あるのはある 2 hits, one being irrelevant ("誇張があるのはある意味では当然のこと")
- [あるといえばある/あると言えばある](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/39630/5010) 6 hits

So `XのはX` is very rare as long as ある is concerned.

As for other adjectives/verbs, I would say there is very little difference between, for example, 遠いには遠いが～, 遠いことは遠いが～ and 遠いのは遠いが～. (遠いといえば遠いが～ is different) But probably 遠いには遠いが sounds a bit more formal and/or literary.

Etymologically, I guess `XのはX` is more closely related to `XことはX` because they are both known as the nominalizers.