# VたにはVた　VS　VるにはVた

Tags: grammar, word-choice

[This Q&A](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/34564/what-is-the-meaning-of-%E8%AA%AD%E3%82%80%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF%E8%AA%AD%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0), explains the form vるにはvた. However, when speaking with some Japanese friends I noticed that they are more likely to use 読んだには読んだ instead of 読むには読んだ. Is that a spoken-language usage?

By the way, they perfectly understand what I want to mean if I use 読むには読んだ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

読んだには読んだ and 読むには読んだ feel exactly the same to me. I personally feel the latter form is a bit more common, but they're both perfectly natural. Note that the first verb never takes ます when you are speaking politely.

- 見るには見た。
- 見たには見た。
- 見るには見ました。
- 見たには見ました。
- [×] 見ますには見ました。
- [×] 見ましたには見ました。

Regarding formality, this には sounds a bit stiff. When talking with friends, 読むには読んだ is okay, but more casual wordings such as "読みはした" and "読む[っちゃ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/39630/5010)読んだ" tend to be preferred.